# How to pass data received from service to angular datatable

Tags: json, angular, angular-services, angular-datatables

I have just started working on Angular 4 and I am trying to render some data which I receive from angular service in json format, into angular-datatable, but whichever option i try its not working for me.
The table is coming, the columns are coming, however the data inside the columns are not displaying.

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance..!!!!

Please find my code below:

**component.html**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FleetDataService } from '../../services/fleet-data.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-dashboard',
   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  private fleetData: any;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  constructor(private getFleetData:FleetDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getFleetData.getFleetData().subscribe(
     fleetData => {
       this.fleetData = fleetData;
       console.log(this.fleetData);
       this.dtTrigger.next();
    },
    err => {
     console.log(err);
    }
 );
 this.dtOptions = {
   pagingType: 'full_numbers',
   columns: [{
     title: 'First Name',
     data: this.fleetData
   }, {
     title: 'Last Name',
     data: this.fleetData
   }, {
     title: 'Score',
     data: this.fleetData
   }]
  };
 }
}
```

**component.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from 
'@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class FleetDataService {

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getFleetData() {
   return this.http.get("../../assets/data/test.json")
     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server 
   Error'));
 }

}
```

**test.json**

```
  [{
    "FirstName": "Jill",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Score": "disqualified"
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Eve",
    "LastName": "Jackson",
    "Score": "94"
  }, {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Score": "80"
  }, {
    "FirstName": "Adam",
    "LastName": "Johnson",
    "Score": "67"
 }]
```

Comment: No console errors?

Comment: No console errors

Comment: Can you try to put the entire definition of this.dtOptions inside the subscribe

Comment: Then i get this error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You set your dtOptions outside the subscribe.

If you do this the fleetData stays empty so dtOptions is never set correctly, because an Observable is asynchronous. I propose this code:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(private getFleetData:FleetDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getFleetData.getFleetData().subscribe(
     fleetData => {
       console.log(fleetData);
       this.buildDtOptions(fleetData)
       this.dtTrigger.next();
    },
    err => {
     console.log(err);
    });
  }

  private buildDtOptions(fleetData: any): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
         pagingType: 'full_numbers',
         columns: [
           {title: 'First Name', data: fleetData}, 
           {title: 'Last Name', data: fleetData}, 
           {title: 'Score', data: fleetData}
         ]
    };
  }
 }
```

For this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`. You can do a spinner (ngIf / else) in the view and when data are loaded you display the datatable

Comment: You mean like a spinner or something,till the data is being displayed?

Comment: I think you are right with the approach, but miss as OP the basics in DataTables. You should have `data: fleetData` in `dtOptions` and in the `columns` section refer to the attributes, i.e `data: 'Firstname'` and so on.

Comment: @pranayanand yes

Comment: @davidkonrad yes I agree with you. The idea is to have a spinner during the loading (ngIf ; else). So the datatable isn't build yet and it will build when all data are fetching

Comment: I added following code in my ngOnInit() function:
ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.display(true);
     this.getFleetData.getFleetData().subscribe(
     fleetData => {
       console.log(fleetData);
       this.buildDtOptions(fleetData);
       this.dtTrigger.next();
    },
    err => {
     console.log(err);
    });
    this.loaderService.display(false);
  }

But still i am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: @pranayanand this.loaderService.display(false); to be inside the subscribe too

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.display(true);
     this.getFleetData.getFleetData().subscribe(
     fleetData => {
       console.log(fleetData);
       this.buildDtOptions(fleetData);
       this.dtTrigger.next();
       this.loaderService.display(false);
    },
    err => {
     console.log(err);
     this.loaderService.display(false);
    });
    
  }
gives this errors
1.ERROR ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
2.TypeError:Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: @pranayanand your first error is about the loaderService?

Comment: @pranayanand what's your datatables npm package for I check it in my side?

Comment: I guess so, If i call the loader outside subscribe i don't get that error, Apologies if i am not getting it correctly

Comment: "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined*" ...because `data` not is attached with an attribute.

Comment: i got it from here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-ajax.

No it doesnt work, but i dont get the "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" error thats all

Comment: @davidkonrad : any tip on how to attach it with an attribute?

Comment: @pranayanand, look at my first comment above.

Comment: @pranayanand sorry I cann't test to know why you have your error. I don't have my computer and on stackblitz I cann't have acces to node_modules to configure the angular-cli

Comment: @mickaelw : Its ok, I really appreciate all the help, whenever you get time, please look into it, if possible.